# Bootstrap dropdown not working?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

The following dropdown isn't working:

http://jsfiddle.net/xws2j/

```
<li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown open">
                  <a href="#" id="drop3" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown 3 <b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop3">
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
```

It activates, but it looks like it is hidden behind something. But I'm not sure what. Can anybody help?

Comment: That jsfiddle seems to work, yet it has no HTML/CSS/Javascript? Does it appear that way for others or is it just me?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  Following jsfiddle update, you have to refresh your browser's cache

Comment: @roasted Many thanks - I wondered why I'd seen some odd looking fiddles today :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  Im wondering how many people will be fooled by this one, really bad the jsfiddle team didn't have change some script name

Answer (score 2):

I have amened your css.

http://jsfiddle.net/xws2j/4/

It was syntax causing this issue. See below.

```
 .collapse {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow: visible \9;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.35s ease;
     -moz-transition: height 0.35s ease;
       -o-transition: height 0.35s ease;
          transition: height 0.35s ease;
}
```

Notice:

```
 overflow: hidden;
 overflow: visible \9;
```

Corrected to:

```
  .collapse {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  -webkit-transition: height 0.35s ease;
     -moz-transition: height 0.35s ease;
       -o-transition: height 0.35s ease;
          transition: height 0.35s ease;
}
```

Comment: Seems unlikely to have been an accident, and more likely to have been something for portability. Also, that's code from Bootstrap, not the OP's code. [It _does_ appear to have been removed in later versions, though.](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/4499)

Comment: It doesn't matter if it was a mistake or not. He asked why it was broken, I showed him. visible \9 is invalid syntax.

Comment: That it's invalid syntax is barely here nor there. There are a million CSS hacks that are _deliberately_ invalid syntax and fix problems for precisely that reason. The issue is whether _this_ hack is causing the problem, and can it be removed "safely"? That it's no longer used in Bootstrap implies yes, but then the solution is to upgrade Bootstrap, not to just hack around in its internal implementation.

Comment: Ahh brilliant thank you! It was from a bootstrap generator that I used. I'll just go with the usual layout.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit I'm not sure I understand your argument. He asked why it was not working. I answered the question.